# Knockout observable array not updating the UI

Tags: knockout.js

I am calling as WEB service and get the JSON data. After that using knockout Js i am binding into a table.After that when user type something in the text bax it filters the data and show in the UI. But currently it is not working. Please find the code below.

```
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AllTasks";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel;
    var url = 'http://localhost:22653/api/AllTasks';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        var FAJobViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.Parameters = ko.observableArray();
            var AllTask = JSON.parse(readJSON(url));
            function readJSON(file) {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('GET', file, false);
                request.send(null);
                if (request.status == 200)
                    return request.responseText;
            };
            self.Parameters = ko.observableArray(AllTask);


            self.query = ko.observable('');
            self.search = function (value) {
                self.JobIDParameters = ko.observableArray();
                debugger;
                for (var x in AllTask) {
                    if (AllTask[x].JobNumber.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                        self.JobIDParameters.push(AllTask[x]);
                    }
                }
                self.Parameters = self.JobIDParameters;

            };

        }
        viewModel = new FAJobViewModel();
        viewModel.query.subscribe(viewModel.search);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("AllTask"));
    }
    );


</script>
<div id="AllTask" class=" container-fluid" style="margin-top:50px">
    <span>JobId</span><input id="txtSearch" placeholder="Search…" type="search" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" " />
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Job Id</th>
                <th>Requestor</th>
                <th>Test Name</th>
                <th>Priority</th>
                <th>CreatedDate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach:Parameters" class=" container-fluid">
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text:JobNumber"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text:Requestor"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text:TaskAbbreviation"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text:Priority"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text:CreatedDate"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Try making this one `self.Parameters = self.JobIDParameters;` to this `self.Parameters(self.JobIDParameters())` .

Comment: How should i do tht?

Comment: mark it as answer if your got your fix .it will be useful to others coming in .

Answer (score 0):

Issue exists where you are assigning resultant filtered data you need avoid using `=` and use `()` convention instead which will keep two way binding intact .

**viewModel :**

```
self.Original= ko.observableArray(AllTask);
self.Parameters = ko.observableArray(AllTask);
self.search = function (value) {
        if(!value){self.Parameters(self.Original())}
        var arr= [];
        ko.utils.arrayForeach(self.Original(),function(item){
        if (item.JobNumber().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase())>= 0)
             {
                 arr.push(item);
             }
        });
          self.Parameters(arr);
    };
```

I made small changes for correct functionality . Hope that helps .

Comment: I am getting like this Unhandled exception at line 113, column 21 in http://localhost:22653/Home/AllTasks

0x800a138a - JavaScript runtime error: Function expected

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: your `jquery.js` or some other js may be not loaded properly . check the console window and see for any errors .